# Retrieve hidden phones number with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Here is my spider :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/items/.'),deny=('sendMessage')), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/item/[a-z\+]+\-[0-9]+') ,deny=('sendMessage')), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/h1/text()').extract_first()
        locations = response.xpath("//*[@id='mylocation']//div[@class='location']")
        list_location = []
        for (i, location) in enumerate(locations):
            location_tab = {}
            phoneitem = []
                data = [
                  ('somedata', ''),
                  ('somedata', ''),
                  ('somedata', ''),
                ]
                request = scrapy.FormRequest(
                        'http://www.example.com/ajax/my-phone',
                        formdata= data,
                        callback=self.parse_for_number
                    )
                request.meta['phoneitem'] = phoneitem
                yield request
                location_tab['phone'] = phoneitem

            location_title = location.xpath("string(.//h3)").extract()
            location_title[0] = ' '.join(location_title[0].split())
            location_address = location.xpath(".//p[@class='address']").extract()
            #if not location_title:
            #    location_title = location.xpath("h3/a/text()").extract()
            location_tab['location_title'] = location_title[0].encode('utf-8')
            location_tab['location_address'] = location_address[0].encode('utf-8')
            list_location.append(location_tab)
            location_title = ''
            location_address = ''
            location_tab = {}
        if name :
            yield { 'name' : name,
                    'url' : url,
                    'locations' : list_location
            }

    def parse_for_number(self, response):
        phoneitem = request.meta['phoneitem']
        phones = response.xpath("//li[@class='phone']/text()").extract()
        for phone in phones:
            phoneitem.append(' '.join(phone.split()))
        yield phoneitem
```

My spider consists of retrieving a list of person (name) in addition to their addresses and their telephone number in each of these addresses (the phone number is displayed through an ajax request with post variables).

The list of phones (phoneitem) always remains empty. Where is the error?

Edit:
How can I store the result of the parse_for_number function in a variable, and use it after?
Since I call the FormRequest in a FOR loop, I can not yield the phone variable to each execution of the function.

Comment: I can retrieve and display phones from http://www.example.com/ajax/my-phone. But in can't store them in the "list_location" variable

Comment: You can retrieve them with `Scrapy` of with a browser?

Comment: 'print phone' actualy display the phone number.

Comment: Your `phoneitem` is an array and you are yielding an array in `parse_for_number`, while scrapy will be expecting a `item` or  `dict`

Comment: I change phoneitem to dict (phoneitem={}). But when parse_for_number yield it, it adds it to the root of the json file, not inside location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !

I use the requests library

```
import requests
request = requests.post('http://www.example.com/ajax/my-phone', cookies=cookies, data=data)

phones = Selector(text=request.content).xpath("//li[@class='phone']/text()").extract()
```